# Cache web view remote html and assets to serve locally

Tags: android, ios, cordova, caching

I'm using a web view inside a cordova app, for a hosted web app.

Much of the content for the cordova web app comes from the server - the shipped app has very little files held locally.

I'd like to cache the response from page loads in the app, so that on subsequent requests, I can serve up the cached version.

I've started looking at [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) and I've got something working that loads a remote URL and then saves that to the phone.. I can then navigate to that saved URL, and it does attempt to load it up, but that's just the start of it - I'd need to intercept and cache all the resources (js and styles) requested too, so that they'd be served up with the app, assuming the links are all relative. The more I look into this, the more effort it seems.

Is there a simple way to do this in Cordova?

EDIT

I've looked at some suggestions which include:

1. HTML5 appCache (cache manifest). But this isn't supported in Cordova any more
2. NSUrlCache. This is iOS specific and I'm looking for something that will work on android and ios

Comment: There are several ways to handle this. HTML5 appCache (cache manifest), setting the cache policy on Cordova's NSURLCache, and/or rolling  your own, which is what you have started to do. Too many options and unknowns to offer any real advice, though.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, NSURLCache is IOS specific, and I thought that the cache manifest wasn't supported in cordova any more?

Comment: Yeah, it really is dependent on what your priorities are. Staying with latest Cordova releases, forking your own, etc. As you have found, there are a lot of cross-platform variances when it comes to Cordova and versions. I usually let the overall product requirements drive many of those decisions and look at Cordova as a starting point for hybrid dev, not an end state. Historically, many of the plugins are just too limited to be used out of box.